# How could Naruto use rasengan in tailed best chakra mode?

Tags: naruto

In EP 296 titled:

**Naruto enters the battle!!**

Naruto used rasengan in tailed beast chakra mode to take down the enemy white Zetsu.

But I thought whenever he tried using rasengan in tailed beast chakra mode, the rasengan got converted into the tailed beast bomb...am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The "Rasengan" was created by the Fourth Hokage, Minato Namikaze, who took three years to develop it. The Rasengan is based on the Beast Ball with Tail, which is the definitive attack of the Beasts with Tail.

So that it isn't difficult to confuse one technique with the other, but answering the question what in fact uses naruto in that chapter is a "partial" rasengan with chakra of the 9 tails beast.

During the manga different versions of this combination are seen, but in any case is the tail beast bomb. It is a fusion between the two techniques or simply the utilisation of Kurama's chakra.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that whenever he used Rasengan in Tailed Beast mode it converted into Tailed Beast bomb. That's because the Nine Tail was not allowing the chakra flow properly and was using Naruto's technique for its own benefit (i.e. hatred, his own nature).

But since he mastered Tailed Beast, i.e. he befriended Kurama, he no longer interfered with Naurto's motives of techniques. He just provide his own chakra to enhance Naruto's technique.

Comment: but...he could use rasengan in tailed beast chakra mode even before he and nine tails were friends..

Comment: then what is your question,please clearify it
you asked "But I thought whenever he tried using rasengan in tailed beast chakra mode, the rasengan got converted into the tailed beast bomb...am I missing something?"

i have answered it @MartianCactus